# VPN, open ports not bound to vpn ip not reachable

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

On my Win10 machine using OpenVPN (AirVPN) I have open ports, some are bound to the VPN ip/adapter, others are bound to 0.0.0.0. Now when I try to connect to these open ports from another external machine I can only connect to those that are bound to the VPN ip, not to the other ones. To clarify, using "netstat -a":

TCP 0.0.0.0:49669 VPN-PC:0 LISTENING <-- can't connect

TCP 10.10.10.10:49668 VPN-PC:0 LISTENING <-- can connect

where 10.10.10.10 is the ip of the VPN interface. Windows Firewall is disabled. What do I need to do to fix this?